# iPad 3 max framerate

Tags: ipad, display, benchmark

Has anyone tried to test the maximum frame rate one an iPad 3 connected to a 120Hz screen for example?

I would like to know if it's possible to achieve more than the 60fps using the any benchmark/test application or a custom test app using CADisplayLink on an external monitor.

Please report the application or game you tested with - I am leaving this wide open in terms of which app so as to get some initial data on what frame rate the hardware is capable of pushing.

Comment: Questions on using the [SDK to develop apps](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/QuartzCore/Reference/CADisplayLink_ClassRef/Reference/Reference.html) are generally [off topic here](http://apple.stackexchange.com/faq). Hit us up in the [chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/38/ask-different-chat) if you need more assistance - you might have better luck on StackOverflow for specific coding questions.

Comment: @bmike: Actually using any kind of application that displays the framerate would be a good solution. The question is not about how to develop or use an SDK... It's specifically about the iPad/hardware.

Comment: OK - I didn't read it that way. How about I re-open it and  let it ride a while. The other moderators will see that I closed it and re-opened it - so we'll see how the community sees it. If they vote it closed - hit us (the moderators) up in the chat room and we can help editing it into shape so others don't interpret it as I did initially.

Comment: @bmike: Edited the question to avoid more confusion.

Answer (score -1):

### [GLBenchmark 2.1](http://itunes.apple.com/app/glbenchmark-2.1/id460948646?mt=8)

($4.99 in App Store)